ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
I’m adding a notification system to my blog website using the noticed gem (v2) by Chris Oliver. I’ve set up a notifier to send email notifications, but I’m encountering an error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)). It seems that a parameter is expected but not provided. How can I resolve this error and ensure the notification receives the correct argument?
usermailer.rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.new_comment.subject
  #
  def new_comment
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: params[:user].email
  end
end

comment_notifier.rb
# To deliver this notification:
#
# CommentNotifier.with(record: @post, message: "New post").deliver(User.all)

class CommentNotifier < ApplicationNotifier
  # Add your delivery methods
  #
  deliver_by :email do |config|
    config.mailer = "UserMailer"
    config.method = "new_comment"

    #why this line expects an argument
    config.params = ->(recipient) { { user: recipient } }
  end
  #
  # bulk_deliver_by :slack do |config|
  #   config.url = -> { Rails.application.credentials.slack_webhook_url }
  # end
  #
  # deliver_by :custom do |config|
  #   config.class = "MyDeliveryMethod"
  # end

  # Add required params
  #
  # required_param :message
end

am calling the notifier from rails console like
CommentNotifier.with(record: Comment.last, message: "New post").deliver(User.last)
below is the stack trace
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.7.2)
irb(main):001:0> CommentNotifier.with(record: Comment.last, message: "New post").deliver(User.last)
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY "comments"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  CommentNotifier Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "noticed_events" ("type", "record_type", "record_id", "params", "created_at", "updated_at", "notifications_count") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["type", "CommentNotifier"], ["record_type", "Comment"], ["record_id", 35], ["params", "{\"message\":\"New post\",\"_aj_symbol_keys\":[\"message\"]}"], ["created_at", "2024-11-08 18:45:25.508349"], ["updated_at", "2024-11-08 18:45:25.508349"], ["notifications_count", 1]]
  Noticed::Notification Insert (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "noticed_notifications" ("type","recipient_type","recipient_id","event_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ('CommentNotifier::Notification', 'User', 5, 38, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING "id"
  TRANSACTION (44.3ms)  COMMIT
Enqueued Noticed::EventJob (Job ID: 4e4dd3f7-1629-4119-acd8-f346a488861c) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000077596c7dd240 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://student-connect-hub/CommentNotifier/38>>
=> 
#<CommentNotifier:0x000077596ce5e178
 id: 38,
 type: "CommentNotifier",
 record_type: "Comment",
 record_id: 35,
 params: {:message=>"New post"},
 created_at: Fri, 08 Nov 2024 18:45:25.508349000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 08 Nov 2024 18:45:25.508349000 UTC +00:00,
 notifications_count: 1>
irb(main):002:0>   CommentNotifier Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "noticed_events".* FROM "noticed_events" WHERE "noticed_events"."type" = $1 AND "noticed_events"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["type", "CommentNotifier"], ["id", 38], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Performing Noticed::EventJob (Job ID: 4e4dd3f7-1629-4119-acd8-f346a488861c) from Async(default) enqueued at 2024-11-08T18:45:25Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000077596cea0fa0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://student-connect-hub/CommentNotifier/38>>
  Noticed::Notification Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "noticed_notifications".* FROM "noticed_notifications" WHERE "noticed_notifications"."event_id" = $1  [["event_id", 38]]
Enqueued Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Email (Job ID: 6ef6cdfa-7c81-474f-8d4d-08449c6dfd5b) to Async(default) with arguments: :email, #<GlobalID:0x000077596cb8fe38 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://student-connect-hub/CommentNotifier::Notification/59>>
Performed Noticed::EventJob (Job ID: 4e4dd3f7-1629-4119-acd8-f346a488861c) from Async(default) in 162.98ms
  CommentNotifier::Notification Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "noticed_notifications".* FROM "noticed_notifications" WHERE "noticed_notifications"."type" = $1 AND "noticed_notifications"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["type", "CommentNotifier::Notification"], ["id", 59], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Performing Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Email (Job ID: 6ef6cdfa-7c81-474f-8d4d-08449c6dfd5b) from Async(default) enqueued at 2024-11-08T18:45:25Z with arguments: :email, #<GlobalID:0x000077596cba7b78 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://student-connect-hub/CommentNotifier::Notification/59>>
  Noticed::Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "noticed_events".* FROM "noticed_events" WHERE "noticed_events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 38], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Error performing Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Email (Job ID: 6ef6cdfa-7c81-474f-8d4d-08449c6dfd5b) from Async(default) in 108.72ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
/home/code-machine/Desktop/work/StudentConnectHub/app/notifiers/comment_notifier.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CommentNotifier>'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_method.rb:50:in `instance_exec'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_method.rb:50:in `evaluate_option'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_methods/email.rb:15:in `params'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_methods/email.rb:10:in `deliver'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_method.rb:32:in `block in perform'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/noticed-2.4.3/lib/noticed/delivery_method.rb:31:in `perform'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:65:in `block in _perform_job'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/i18n-1.14.1/lib/i18n.rb:322:in `with_locale'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:65:in `use_zone'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/timezones.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Timezones>'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:64:in `_perform_job'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:20:in `_perform_job'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:52:in `perform_now'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `block in perform_now'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:25:in `block in instrument'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:35:in `instrument'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `perform_now'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `block in perform_now'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `tag_logger'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `perform_now'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:30:in `block in execute'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:54:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `block in wrap'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:28:in `execute'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activejob-7.0.7.2/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb:70:in `perform'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
/home/code-machine/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'





I don't see that syntax (config.params = lambda) anywhere in the documentation but what happens if you remove the recipient argument from the lambda e.g. config.params = ->{ { user: recipient } }? Again I have no idea what this is intended to do but the lambda argument appears to be what is causing the error since it is being called without one.
